# Cannot compile using the newpx package

Tags: fonts, errors, pdftex

As basic as:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

does not compile. It issues an error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file T1-TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular-lnum-kern-liga--base):
 Font T1-TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular-lnum-kern-liga--base at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I am using MiKTeX 2.9. I suppose the font has not been created or I am doing something wrong but I cannot get it to compile. An insights? How can I get the font created?

Comment: Run updmap on the command line to update your user map-files.

Comment: Did you verify that the newpxtext and newpxmath packages have been installed?

Comment: Yes they are! That is why I asked how to create them cause it was not compiling

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That solved the problem. Please post as answer and if you could elaborate on what updmap does as opposed to refreshing the fndb or recreating the formats? What is the actual purpose of updmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@urlikefischer provided the answer. By running `updmap` in `cmd` prompt, the problem is solved. I did some research about what `updmap` is and this is what I found:

> **updmap** - Update font map files for TeX output drivers.
>
> **updmap-sys**  - Update font map files for TeX output drivers
>   system-wide.
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
>    updmap is a utility that creates font configuration files for dvips(1),
>    pdftex(1),   xdvi(1),   ps2pk(1),  gsftopk(1),  dvipdfm(1)  and  (soon)
>    dvipdfmx(1).  In an ideal world, updmap would be unnecessary -- each of
>    these  programs  would  read  the same configuration file to learn what
>    fonts are available and how they should be treated.  As  things  stand,
>    however,  each  of  these  tools  has subtly different requirements and
>    thereby needs its own font configuration  file.   updmap  creates  font
>    configuration  files  for  all  of these programs from a single source,
>    allowing you to easily keep all the different  configuration  files  in
>    sync.
>
>    updmap  reads a configuration file, updmap.cfg(5) and, depending on the
>    options specified in that file and on the  command  line,  updmap  will
>    write  generated  map files to a directory of your choosing (via one of
>    the --*outputdir options), or automatically determine  where  to  place
>    the  files.   In  the  latter  case, it tries to use the tree where the
>    variable TEXMFVAR points  to.   When  used  with  the  options  --edit,
>    --setoption, --enable, --disable, or --syncwithtrees, updmap will first
>    write updmap.cfg(5) and regenerate the map files only if this file  has
>    been changed.
> ```

There is also a warning provided:

> Do not edit this file directly. Run initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
>   to edit configuration settings for outline fonts.

Here are the links to the above:

1. http://docs.miktex.org/manual/updmapcfg.html
2. http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/updmap1.html