# Still can't compile with newpx

Tags: fonts, errors

I have the same problem as this question: [Cannot compile using the newpx package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110888/cannot-compile-using-the-newpx-package)

But the solution there doesn't work for me. After running `updmap` several times I still can't compile even the simple

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file T1-TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular-lnum-kern-liga--base):
Font T1-TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular-lnum-kern-liga--base at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I tried `updmap --force` and `--admin` too. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: Which LaTeX distribution? Compiles just fine for me using TUG TeX Live 2012 (frozen).

Comment: @daleif MiKTeX 2.9

Comment: How did you install the font? I tend to recommend TUG TL to my users as it adds everything and it just works. Lots of people seem to have problems with either MikTeX or the Ubuntu version of TL.

Comment: @daleif I will now try to reinstall it with the built-in package manager, because it's possible that it was an on-the-fly install during compilation which MiKTeX automatically does, although the installation procedure should be the same.

Comment: Might be an idea. You could test to see if it finds some of the font files, e.g. `kpsewhich TeXGyrePagellaX-Regular.pfb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I uninstalled the `newpx` package, ran a full update of MiKTeX, and reinstalled the package. Then the compilation failed with an `etex.sty not found` error. I had to install the package `miktex-etex-base-2.9` from the package manager because the earlier `miktex-etex-base` has been removed as obsolete during the update. After that everything worked again.